# Return only most recent entry per id

Tags: sql, firebird, greatest-n-per-group, firebird2.5

I'm running this SQL script on my Firebird 2.5-DB:

```
SELECT aktivitaet.creationdatetime,
(select STRINGPROPVALUE from PROPERTY WHERE PROPERTYNAME LIKE 'GlobalDokPfad') as basispfad, 
aktivitaet.pfad, 
cast(rechnung.datum as date),
rechnung.nummer, 
projekt.code, 
cast(rechnung.verrtotal as numeric(10,2)), 
projekt.betreffend 
FROM rechnung 
INNER JOIN aktivitaetenlink ON rechnung.bold_id=aktivitaetenlink.eintraege 
INNER JOIN aktivitaet ON aktivitaetenlink.aktivitaeten=aktivitaet.bold_id 
Left JOIN projekt ON aktivitaet.projekt=projekt.bold_id 
where rechnung.datum >= '01.01.2013' and rechnung.verrechnet=1 and aktivitaet.typ=15104 
order by rechnung.nummer, aktivitaet.creationdatetime DESC;
```

It returns me this result:

```
CREATIONDATETIME,BASISPFAD,PFAD,CAST,NUMMER,CODE,CAST,BETREFFEND 
"14.05.2014 16:53:25";"C:\Daten\Demo\Dokumente";"C:\Daten\Demo\Dokumente\Comte AG,Biel-Bienne\100027_2.doc";"18.12.2014 00:00:00";"100027";;"9491.0499999999993"; 
"14.05.2014 16:53:01";"C:\Daten\Demo\Dokumente";"C:\Daten\Demo\Dokumente\Comte AG, Biel-Bienne\100027.doc";"18.12.2014 00:00:00";"100027";;"9491.0499999999993"; 
"17.10.2014 14:06:08";"C:\Daten\Demo\Dokumente";"C:\Daten\Demo\Dokumente\Baumann GmbH, Luzern\100031.doc";"17.10.2014 00:00:00";"100031";;"842.39999999999998"; 
"16.04.2015 09:51:03";"C:\Daten\Demo\Dokumente";"C:\Daten\Demo\Dokumente\Comte AG, Biel-Bienne\100033.doc";"01.04.2015 00:00:00";"100033";;"1080012.05";
"01.04.2015 16:47:58";"C:\Daten\Demo\Dokumente";"C:\Daten\Dokumente\100033.doc";"01.04.2015 00:00:00";"100033";"COMTE AG";"1080012.05";"Treuhand" 
"15.04.2015 09:24:46";"C:\Daten\Demo\Dokumente";"100035.doc";"15.04.2015 00:00:00";"100035";;"3240.";
```

My Problem:

If there exist 2 records with the same rechnung.nummer (i.e 1000033 / 1000027), only one record (the one with the last aktivitaet.creationdatetime) should be in the result.

Comment: Do a GROUP BY, with MAX(aktivitaet.creationdatetime).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When faced with multiple results from a join and you want to match the most recently dated row, a correlated subquery in the join criteria is one I have found to be quite simple to write and quite fast in execution:

```
...
JOIN    aktivitaet  a
    ON  a.bold_id = al.aktivitaeten
    AND a.creationdatetime =(
        SELECT  Max( creationdatetime )
        FROM    aktivitaet
        WHERE   bold_id = a.bold_id )
...
```

Comment: Thank you TommCatt for your great help. It works now as it should. Have a good day! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the [MySQL manual (though it's valid for all DBMS implementing the SQL '92 Standard)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//example-maximum-column-group-row.html):

### The Rows Holding the Group-wise Maximum of a Certain Column

*Task: For each article, find the dealer or dealers with the most expensive price.*

This problem can be solved with a subquery like this one:

```
SELECT article, dealer, price
FROM   shop s1
WHERE  price=(SELECT MAX(s2.price)
              FROM shop s2
              WHERE s1.article = s2.article);

+---------+--------+-------+
| article | dealer | price |
+---------+--------+-------+
|    0001 | B      |  3.99 |
|    0002 | A      | 10.99 |
|    0003 | C      |  1.69 |
|    0004 | D      | 19.95 |
+---------+--------+-------+
```

The preceding example uses a correlated subquery, which can be inefficient (see Section 13.2.10.7, “Correlated Subqueries”). Other possibilities for solving the problem are to use an uncorrelated subquery in the FROM clause or a LEFT JOIN.

**Uncorrelated subquery:**

```
SELECT s1.article, dealer, s1.price
FROM shop s1
JOIN (
  SELECT article, MAX(price) AS price
  FROM shop
  GROUP BY article) AS s2
  ON s1.article = s2.article AND s1.price = s2.price;
```

**LEFT JOIN:**

```
SELECT s1.article, s1.dealer, s1.price
FROM shop s1
LEFT JOIN shop s2 ON s1.article = s2.article AND s1.price < s2.price
WHERE s2.article IS NULL;
```

The LEFT JOIN works on the basis that when s1.price is at its maximum value, there is no s2.price with a greater value and the s2 rows values will be NULL.

Comment: Quoting the MySQL manual on a Firebird question might not always work (although in this case it does).